# quantile regression parameter for desired confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, quantiles, quantile-regression

I want to plot C% confidence intervals for a regressor (GradientBoosting in my case).

I found this example on scikit-learn documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_quantile.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-gradient-boosting-quantile-py where the area between the quantiles (alpha) 0.05 and 0.95 is indicated as 95% confidence interval.

Two questions:

- Is correct the scikit-learn example? Shouldn't be 90% confidence interval with those quantiles equal to 0.05 and 0.95?
- If I want to plot confidence interval of C%, is it correct to pick alpha_low = (1-C)/2 and alpha_high = (1 - (1-C)/2) ?

thank you!

Comment: Is the [tag:quantile-regression] tag relevant here?

Comment: a regression problem with 'quantile' loss is related to quantile-regression, isn't it?

Comment: This is not obvious from your post, though maybe it is hidden under the link. In that case it is OK.